# Probability for Continuous Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability

If $X$ has a continuous uniform distribution on the interval from $0$ to $10$, then what is $P[X+\frac{10}{X} > 7]$?

I got to $P[(X-5)(X-2)>0]$, which then I thought would be $P[X>5] + P[X>2]$. I need help with the reasoning after the factorization part.

Comment: $(X-2)(X-5)$ is positive if $X-2$ and $X-5$ are both positive or both negative.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the event $\{(X-5)(X-2) \leq 0\}$ is the same than $\{X \in [2;5]\}$ (which is the complementary event of the one you're looking for). So the event you want is $\{X<2\} \cup \{X>5\}$. These event are disjoint, so you have $P(\{X<2\} \cup \{X>5\})=P(X<2)+P(X>5)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the condition $(X-5)(X-2)>0$ can be restated as a logical combination of the separate conditions $X>5$ and $X>2.$ That should tell you how to partition the interval $[0,10]$ into a finite number of pieces, the probability of which can be computed separately (and since they are disjoint, their probabilities can be added - unlike $X>5$ and $X>2$).